# Download satellite/maps images (from Google Maps or Live Maps?)

Tags: silverlight, google-maps, deepzoom

I'm building a little play project and I'd like to use satellite images of a town inside deepzoom, what's the easiest way to get them? I'm sure there's a MUCH better way than PrtScn, I've tried  google maps downloader but it doesn't download satellite images and it's company don't seem to be offering it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Deep Earth, unless what you're trying to build is what deep earth give you - in which case it may remove all the fun ;)

http://www.codeplex.com/deepearth

If you want to go your own way, then it used to be that you could just manually request the various image tiles directly from the MS Virtual Earth server hosting them, if you could calculate the [quad keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) and build the correct URL, thus bypassing their payment model.  Whilst I know they were looking to cut out this loop hole, that's certainly what early versions of Deep Earth did.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Virtual Earth has SOAP and AJAX-based services that you can use in your application.  The service has a Staging and Production version.  Using the Staging version is free, and could easily serve the needs of a "play project."  The Production version costs money and can serve info to a large application with many users.

http://dev.live.com/VirtualEarth/

However there is some registration required to get working with the Staging sdk.  You can get started here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980844.aspx

Comment: I've been playing with this while I was waiting for an answer, problem is I'm literally just starting to learn javascript so I'd spend most of my time learning the ins and outs of that rather than building what I wanted to build. I wanna learn javascript but what I'm building now could be useful.